# BigQuery: How do I check for every string element of column1 whether it is contained in column2?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery.
My data looks like this, I start with Table1 and Table2:

**Table1**

| Str1 |
| --- |
| "a" |
| "b" |

**Table2**

| id | Str2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | "car" |
| 2 | "apple" |
| 3 | "banana" |
| 4 | "bob" |

How can I design my query to get Table3?

It has the Table2.id if the value from Table1 is found as substring in Table2.Str2.

**Table3**

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 3 |
| 0 | 4 |

Thank you!

Comment: Hey Twfdsa, welcome to Stackoverflow! I can't quite grasp what it is you're trying to do with Table 3. What does column a and column b refer to in Table3, are you counting how many times a letter occurs from table 2?

Comment: In Table3 the column headers are the values from Table1. Table3 checks whether the string value in Table1 (e.g. "a") is contained in Str2 (e.g. Yes for Table2.id=1,2,3 but No for Table2.id=4). If yes, Table3.a=Table2.id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select * from (
  select id, str1, regexp_contains(str2, str1) contained
  from table2, table1
)
pivot (min(contained) for str1 in ('a', 'b'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

In case if you actually need output look exact as in your question - use below

```
select if(a, id, 0) a, if(b, id, 0) b from (
  select id, str1, regexp_contains(str2, str1) contained
  from table2, table1
)
pivot (min(contained) for str1 in ('a', 'b'))
```

in this case  - output is

[image]